# What is the best place to call web services in iOS application with MVVMC architecture?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, mvvm, architecture

Currently I'm developing an iOS application by using MVVMC architecture. I was getting some idea about MVVMC by reading this [article](https://medium.com/@alex.hsieh/mvvmc-with-storyboard-in-ios-4c97ffdfd7b2) . As a typical MVVM model we know all the major app controllers like web service calls should call in the ViewModel class. But in the MVVMC architecture we can user either Coordinator or ViewModel to call web services. I couldn't figure out what's the best place for this.

I'm currently trying to implement user list page of the application  using UITableViewController. Following are the some parts of my UserCoordinator and UserViewModel classes.

---

**UserCoordinator**

```
class UsersCoordinator: Coordinator {

var window: UIWindow
weak var delegate: UsersCoordinatorDelegate?

var  selectedCity: City?

init(window: UIWindow) {
    self.window = window
}

func start() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Users", bundle: nil)
    if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "list") as? UsersListController {
        var viewModel = UsersListViewModel()
        viewModel.delegate = self as UsersListViewModelDelegate
        viewModel.veiwController = vc
        vc.viewModel = viewModel
        vc.coordinationDelegate = self as CoordinationDelegate
        let nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)
        window.rootViewController = nav
    }

}
```

---

**UserViewModel**

```
 protocol UsersListViewModelDelegate: class  {
    func selectUser(viewController: UIViewController, city: City)
}

struct UsersListViewModel {
    var delegate: UsersListViewModelDelegate?
    weak var veiwController: UsersListController!
    var source = [String]()

    init() {
        for user in users {
            source.append(user.name)
        }
    }

    func selectRow(row: NSInteger) {
        delegate?.selectUser(viewController: veiwController, user: users[row])
    }

    fileprivate var users: [User] {
        get {
            //web service call??
        }
```

Where should I call the web service here? As I have read theoretically Coordinator is the dedicated place for application routing. So according to that it's better to call web services in ViewModel. But I feel it's better to call web services in the Coordinator because it'll load data very quickly and populate the viewModel. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

You need to understand the purpose of ViewModel and Co-ordinator to know what should contains what. The responsibility of a **ViewModel** is to prepare data for the View and handles the business logic for preparing that data. It binds data to UI elements and changes UI as soon as data changes. So ViewModel should be the one which should contains the service and all calls should be made from it.

The responsibility of **co-ordinator** is to handles the navigation of application by showing the appropriate ViewController with all it's dependencies which includes the ViewModel. So it also prepares the ViewModel and injects the service in it not use that service to manipulate data.

So if I summarise, Co-ordinator should be the one who prepares a ViewModel with it's dependencies which includes the injecting webservice in it and ViewModel should be the one who use that service and makes all the call for getting data from the persistence .

For more clear idea you can check my sample application on **MVVM-C** at my **[Github](https://github.com/osama10/MVVM-C-Example)**

Comment: I think this should be preferred since it has decoupling benefits and also makes it easier to write tests for other layers

Answer (score 4):

As I researched through the internet there is no convention where to invoke your web services. It's totally depend on your project implementation. Either you can invoke them on your Coordinator or ViewModel class. Since we are using Coordinator to initialize

1. ViewController
2. ViewModel

Inside the Coordinator class as I have posted above. We can use same start() function to invoke the web services as following.

```
func start() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Users", bundle: nil)
    if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "list") as? UsersListController {
        let uDs = UserDataService(pClient:APIClient())
        uDs.getUserDetails { (response, status) in
            if (status == APIClient.APIResponseStatus.Success) {
                if let resArrray = response as? [User] {
                    var viewModel = UsersListViewModel.init(userList: resArrray)
                    viewModel.delegate = self as UsersListViewModelDelegate
                    viewModel.veiwController = vc
                    vc.viewModel = viewModel
                    vc.coordinationDelegate = self as CoordinationDelegate
                    let nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)
                    self.window.rootViewController = nav
                }
            } else {
                //error alert
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's better to invoke web service calls inside the Coordinator class. Because after invokes  the web service according to the response we can controll the view navigation. Such like if response get success we could create a ViewController class and load it. Otherwise we could load an error popup. Meantime we could take enough time to the web service call and populate those data to the viewModel.

Based on what I have found through the internet , I have implemented a sample project using MVVM-C architecture. I have hosted it in GitHub. You can find it in [here](https://github.com/TharinduKetipe/iOSMVVMC-NetworkingArchitecture).

By refering this poroject you can have a clear idea about to how to implement view navigations using MVVM-C pattern, How to invoke web services, How to populate viewModels from data etc.

Comment: And where will you show HUD ?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to architecture, there's no silver bullet.
Keeping that in mind MVVM-C is one of the most clean, easily testable and modular pattern, so it's great that you are going ahead with it.

You are free to customize the architecture to suit your requirements.
Having said that, considering your current design I think it would be best to create a Service class, call it WebService. This class will perform networking operations under the supervision of the Coordinator. The Coordinator will

1. Init WebService
2. Perform network calls
3. Init the ViewModel with the fetched data (or instruct the ViewModel to handle a failed network call)

Comment: Yes. I already created a service class ,looking where to invoke that methods. As you said I also feel invoke in the coordinator is better. Thank you very much.